How to design nested horizontal scrollviews in SwiftUI?
I am trying to design something similar to the following scrollviews in which when I click on the "Clothing" category another horizontal scrollview appears with different subcategories. Also, I want to implement the similar back button that navigates back to the previous "super-categories".


Below is my implementation for one horizontal scrollview (the top image above). My question is how to implement the second (or nested) horizontal scrollview so that if I click on one category "clothing" the second scrollview (the bottom image) shows up. Thanks.
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 5) {
            ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                Button(action:{
                    selectedCat = category   
                }, label:{
                    Text(category)
                    .font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter",fixedSize: 20))
                })
                .padding(.horizontal,10)
                .padding(.vertical,5)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(selectedCat == category ? Color(UIColor(red: 143/255, green: 93/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)).cornerRadius(40).opacity(0.7) : Color.white.cornerRadius(40).opacity(0))
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 50)
        .background(Color(UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 248/255, blue: 242/255,    alpha: 0.6)).cornerRadius(40))
    }
    .onChange(of: selectedCat) { _ in
        proxy.scrollTo(selectedCat)
    }
}


I don't think this is another view, rather it's a different set of data represented in a similar manner. If you have something like SelectedCategory -> Selected SubCategory -> SelectedSub SubCategory in your logic.
What you can do is to make those variables optional and if the first category is set you would show the sub category items and so on. Once you hit the back button you would clear the selected category or sub category.

Thanks, @Agent Smith for your comment. This is one way I am trying to build; however, for this specific example, I think NavigationStack should be used as Benzy Neez mentioned below.

A regular NavigationStack would be one way to implement the navigation. This gives you the back-button functionality for free.
Below is an updated version of your example to show it working. The key changes:

The top-level parent is a NavigationStack, which is initialized with a path.
The buttons append the selected category to the path.
The nested content is launched by the closure to .navigationDestination. You will probably want to implement the nested page in a similar way as the parent.

Also, you might like to consider these changes:

Add .scrollTargetLayout() to the LazyHStack and .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned) to the ScrollView, to give sticky scrolling behavior.
For the buttons, it looks like you can just use a Capsule as background shape, instead of clipping to a RoundedRectangle.
There is no need to create a Color from a UIColor, it is easier to pass the parameters to Color.init instead.
The modifier .cornerRadius is deprecated, use .clipShape instead.
The version of .onChange that you were using is also deprecated. Change to the version taking either 0 or 2 parameters.
Similarly, .foregroundColor is deprecated, use .foregroundStyle instead.

struct ContentView: View {
    let categories = ["NEW IN", "COLLECTIONS", "CLOTHING", "SHOES", "ACCESSORIES"]
    @State private var selectedCat = ""
    @State private var navPath = [String]()

    private var categoryOverview: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                        Button {
                            selectedCat = category
                            navPath.append(category)
                        } label:{
                            Text(category)
                                .font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter", fixedSize: 20))
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        .padding(.vertical, 5)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        .background(
                            Capsule()
                                .fill(selectedCat == category
                                      ? Color(red: 143/255, green: 93/255, blue: 0/255, opacity: 0.7)
                                      : .clear
                                )
                        )
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 50)
                .background(
                    Color(red: 255/255, green: 248/255, blue: 242/255, opacity: 0.6)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40))
                )
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .onChange(of: selectedCat) { oldVal, newVal in
                proxy.scrollTo(newVal)
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            categoryOverview
                .navigationTitle("")
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { category in
                    Text("Nested page for \(category)")
                        .navigationTitle(category)
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                }
        }
    }
}


Thanks, @Benzy Neez for your recommendations. Since I have nested pages as shown in the images, the ideal implementation would be feeding subcategories to the "categoryView" based on the "category" value. (categoryView(subCategory: retrurnSubCategoryFor(category))) within the .navigationDestination. Is it possible to convert "categoryView" to a struct with "subCategory" input?

@Soroushm I expect so, try it.
